# How to reduce font width using css. I want to add a thin font using regular font

Tags: css, fonts, width

I want to know how to reduce font-width using css. I want to add a thin font using regular font.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, this is [not the kind of question Stackoverflow is for](/help/how-to-ask), this is the kind of question you can just search the web for (including to discover that this is not a thing CSS can do)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for thin font

`{font-weight:300;}`

or

`{font-weight:normal;}` 
   for Normal Font